# OS X Send data to another app

Tags: macos, cocoa, finder

I have an sandboxed OS X app that is capable to open files through Finder services and the "Open with…" option from contextual menus. I have made another sandboxed app that should send compatible files to the first app.

How can I perform an "Open with" action programmatically? I could use a service interaction too. Is that even possible? I guess I could register an URL Scheme in my first app but I'd prefer not having to release an update if everything can be done on sender app

Thx

Comment: Why won't you use simple unix socket for data communication between the 2 processes ?

Comment: I was under the impression that perform an Open with action was a simple task. As I said, I'd like to avoid changing the receiving app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to open a normal file, then take a look at

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openFile:@"/path/to/file" withApplication:@"YourApp"];
```

You can find it [here in the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/openFile:withApplication:).

Comment: Oh man this is embarrassing :D I can't believe I missed it. Thank you. Your answer is correct (it should be `[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace]` tho) but this method only allow to send a single file. I've ended using `
openURLs:withAppBundleIdentifier:options:additionalEventParamDescriptor:launchIdentifiers:` instead to pass a bunch of files. Thank you.